# Output HTML with Jade (within ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, pug

I have app controllers file that fetches information on procedures from a database, one of the pieces of information is the document regarding that procedure.

The problem im facing is, if there is HTML within the document JADE will not render it just uses html entities!

Now i know about `!{VAR}` and `p=!{VAR}` but when i do that i get:

```
Cannot read property 'Doc' of undefined
```

The Snippet of code that gets the information:

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('APIHelpCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, $q, FormSvc, ApplicationSvc) {

    FormSvc.setOptions($scope)
    $scope.results = []

$scope.fetch=function(searchTerm) {
    $scope.results.length = 0
    searchTerm = searchTerm || '';
    return $scope.fetch({
        fetchAPI:'FETCHAPI='+searchTerm,
        multiRow:true,
        fetchTarget:'helpProcs',
        notLoggedIn:true
    })
}

$scope.pushResults=function(DescOnly){
    if (DescOnly == false) {
        $scope.results.push({name:buildObject.proccessName,Doc:buildObject.Doc,params:ar})
    }
}
```

Snippet from the JADE file (the part i cannot figure out)

```
div.results(ng-show="results.length > 0")
    h3 API Help
    .table-responsive
        table.table.table-striped
            thead
                tr
                    th Procedure
                    th.hideOnPrint &nbsp;
            tbody
                tr(ng-repeat='proc in results')
                    td.printView 
                        p(ng-click='viewProcedure(proc.name)') {{ proc.name }}
                        p.helpDocumentation !{proc.Doc}
```

like i previously mentioned `!{proc.Doc}` is causing the cannot read property error - but if i change it too {{proc.Doc}} it can read it perfectly fine (just without rendering the HTML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it

Used `ng-bind-html` and sanitized the html